# Can I use LINQ to get all kinds of control present in my form?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I want to display into a listBox all types of control available in my form (no duplicates).

I tried this:

```
var controls = from c in this.Controls
               select c;

foreach (var x in controls)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(x);
    listBox1.Items.Add(sb.ToString());
}
```

It's not working. :(

**Edit:**

`Error: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern 
        for source type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'.

        'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable`

Comment: what doesnt work? is there an error?

Comment: here: `Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'.  'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ is overkill for this task. So is using a `StringBuilder`. You can get this simply with:

```
foreach (var x in this.Controls)
    listBox1.Items.Add(x.GetType().ToString());
```

Or for the distinct type names:

```
foreach(var typeName in this.Controls.OfType<Control>().Select(c => c.GetType().ToString()).Distinct())
    listBox1.Items.Add(typeName);
```

Edit: for the exact same result as you're getting now, don't use `.GetType()`. Just call `.ToString()` directly on the control. Your question says "types of control," though, so I'm not sure what you're aiming for.

Comment: @Ian Henry: just exploring LINQ :)

Comment: I used your first solution it was fine but I still get duplicates for the same control.... your second solution throws an error which is the same of what I posted.

Comment: Right, that would make sense... I've edited it with the explicit type declaration which should fix the problem.

Comment: Yep; my bad. Edited again, and actually tested this time. Seems `ControlCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<Control>`...principle of least surprise, anyone?

Comment: I think I have to ask it here in SO for the solution :)

Comment: Is the new solution not working for you? What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: oh.. sorry! I just saw your edited answer... it's working already :)

Comment: I find your solution more readable, and I'm giving you the credit... Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 4):

you need to write it like this

```
var controls=from Control control in this.Controls
                    select control;
```

Hope this will work

Comment: (from Control thisControl in this.Controls select thisControl).Distinct();

Comment: it appears two buttons are distinct because they have unique `Text` property. so basically `Distinct()` doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Why can't I add where in this linq statement?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var controls=from Control control in this.Controls.OfType<Control>()
             select control;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working! no duplicates, I just added `control.GetType().ToString()`

```
var controls = (from Control control in this.Controls
               select control.GetType().ToString()).Distinct();

foreach (var x in controls)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(x);
    listBox2.Items.Add(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be better. Isn't it?

```
var controls = (from Control control in this.Controls 
               select control.GetType().ToString()).Distinct();
this.listBox2.Items.AddRange(controls.ToArray());
```